# Anaconda is missing from Azure VM after restarting

Tags: azure

Yesterday I have installed Anaconda in Azure VM(ubuntu, 2 gb plan), after that I have stopped  VM  to save credits.

Today  I have started and logged to Azure VM(different public IP since azure will change the VM ip after stop and start), Anaconda is missing.

I have installed mysql also which perfectly working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you restart VM it should not lose the files , however if your VM get crashed you will not be able to access your VM as well as your data but that doesn't mean you will loss your data. Your data will be stored there in the blob storage.

As a best practice you need to do is- a[`ttach the blob storage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/dn495298(v=azure.100)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) properly to some other vm or new vm to access it again.

As you mentioned in the question , if you want to save money you can explore Azure [`DevTest labs`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/devtest-lab/)